# Python is auto-escaping backslashes in variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux

I'm currently trying to debug a problem where Python 3 keeps escaping backslashes in a variable.

**Situation** 
I have a Kubernetes Secret configured and I can see it as env variable called *SECRET* inside my debian-based container using `env | grep SECRET`. The Secret contains a Password that consists of alphabetical characters and multiple single backslashes *e.g. *"h\ell\o"*. I  now want to use that secret in my python code. I want to read it from an env variable so I don't have to write it in my code in plain text. 
I use `secret=os.getenv("SECRET")` to reference the env variable and initialize a variable containing the secret. Using the python interactive shell calling *secret* directly shows, that it contains *"h\\ell\\o"* because Python is automatically escaping the backslashes. Calling `print(secret)` returns "h\ell\o" as *print* is interpreting the double backslashes as escaped backslashes. 
I now cannot use the variable *SECRET* to insert the password, since it always inserts it containing double backslashes, which is the wrong password.
[Image showing the described situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUIol.png)

**Question** 
Is there a way to disable auto escaping, or to replace the escaped backslashes? I tried several methods using `codecs.encode() or codecs.decode()`. I also tried using `string.replace()`
I cannot change the password.

Comment: "Using the python interactive shell calling secret directly shows, that it contains "h\\ell\\o" because Python is automatically escaping the backslashes." No, it does not. It shows that it contains `h\ell\o`, because that is how `h\ell\o` is *represented as a string literal*. "Calling print(secret) returns "h\ell\o"" No, it does not. It returns `None`. It *displays* `h\ell\o`, because *that is what the string actually contains*. "I now cannot use the variable SECRET to insert the password" Yes, you can. "since it always inserts it containing double backslashes" No, it does not.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I am voting to close this question because *there is not an actual problem being described here*. The output you see is correct, and the string is what you expect it to be. The issue is a misconception about what should be expected; or rather, a confusion between *representations of* things and the things themselves. Notice how you are worried about the backslashes getting doubled up, but *not* about the surrounding quotes appearing out of nowhere? The backslash doubling is the same as the quoting. It is not part of the actual string.

Comment: Just like how if you display a list and see `[1, 2, 3]`, none of the elements of that list are commas, or square brackets.

Comment: The length of "h\ell\o" is 7 and the length of the variable "secret" is also 7. They contain the same string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `repr()` to get the exact representation of your string.

An example for your use-case may look something like this:

```
>>> secret = "h\\ell\\o"
>>> print(secret)
h\ell\o
>>> print(repr(secret))
'h\\ell\\o'
>>> fixed_secret = repr(secret).replace("'", "") # Remove added ' ' before and after your secret since ' ' only represent the string's quotes
>>> print(fixed_secret)
h\\ell\\o
>>>
>>> # Just to make sure that both, secret and fixed_secret, are of type string
>>> type(secret)
<class 'str'>
>>> type(fixed_secret)
<class 'str'>
>>>
```